# Swift: How to make a view a fixed size no matter what size class

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a UIView with a fixed size of width: 200, Height: 100 to be centred at the bottom of my view controller using:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    var 
    self.infoView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.minX, y: view.frame.maxY, width: 200, height: 100)
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}
```

But this code is not having the desired result as the UiView size is changing on each screen size and is not centered.

To be clear, I want infoView to be centred in the middle of all view controllers and a fixed size no matter what screen size is running it. Is this possible?

Comment: Is the view in storyboard? If so, just fix the height and width constraint, the bottom constraints and the center x constraint

Comment: If you use autolayout set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false and set its `heightAnchor` and `widthAnchor`, respectively. If you don't use autolayout, set the auto resizing mask to []

Comment: Setting the constraints John suggested and the translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints to false seems to have done the trick. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Of course you can do it in Interface Builder, but if you want to do it programmatically, here's an idea that will work on a view controller:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let width: CGFloat = 200
    let height: CGFloat = 200
    let x = (view.frame.maxX / 2) - (width / 2)
    let y = (view.frame.maxY / 2) - (height / 2)
    let frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)

    let centeredView = UIView(frame: frame)

    centeredView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    view.addSubview(centeredView)
}
```